# display all elements in svg in a fixed area

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have some javascript code that dynamically creates SVG polygons at various locations. Currently if a polygon is created outside of the range of the SVG element's width and height, then it isn't displayed. I would like the polygons to scale down so that each polygon is visible, within the specified area.

As an example this only displays one triangle:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,50 " fill="blue"></polygon>
    <polygon points="100,0 100,100 200,50 " fill="blue"></polygon>
</svg>
```

but I would like it to display something closer to what this displays (two triangles scaled to fit inside a 100 by 100 box,) without having to change the points myself:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <polygon points="0,0 0,100 50,50 " fill="blue"></polygon>
    <polygon points="50,0 50,100 100,50 " fill="blue"></polygon>
</svg>
```

This seems like it should be easy to do but I searched for "svg scale to fit" and "display all elements in svg in a fixed area" but I couldn't find anything related to my problem

Comment: That's not the way SVGs work. They have `viewbox` attributes which define the co-ordinate space....once you define that your JS should use the maximum values as upper limits when adding the polygon points.

Comment: In my case it seems easier to set the view box based on the maximum points in the polygons. This still seems like a common enough use case that it could be done just by setting an attribute but if I have to do it myself, so be it.